# Local DNS for SOCKS5

Tags: proxy, dns

I want to use dnscrypt proxy for queries, but it's not working on tor.

[Same question as this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261159/how-to-use-a-custom-dns-and-socks5-at-the-same-time)

[I found this solution](https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=15097.0)

Firefox is working properly.

I also tried privoxy over tor but not working as I wanted...

How can I use my running locally dns server on tor ?

Answer (score 0):

With DNSCrypt, maybe you didn't set the flag **force_tcp** to **true** or maybe the connectivity test should be interfering.

Add these lines to your DNSCrypt config and see if it works:

```
force_tcp = true
netprobe_timeout = 0
```